How to Set Dynamic Base Href for Clientlib Generated Using Angular SPA in AEM?
I'm trying to generate a clientlib for an Angular SPA in AEM using aem-clientlib-generator. By default, the baseHref (or deployUrl) for the resources folder in the clientlib is /etc.clientlibs/<proj-name>/clientlibs/clientlib-angular/resources.
This works fine in the local AEM environment (http://localhost:4502/). However, in other environments, we have paths like /auth or /pub after the host URL, e.g., https://aem-dev-url/auth or https://aem-dev-url/pub.
In these cases, the resources URL should become: https://aem-dev-url/auth/etc.clientlibs/<proj-name>/clientlibs/clientlib-angular/resources, depending on whether it's the auth or pub instance. How can I achieve this?
I tried configuring APP_BASE_HREF dynamically based on the URL in app.module.ts, setting it to /auth or /pub, but this doesn't work for accessing the resources folder in the generated clientlib.
How can I provide a dynamic base URL when generating the clientlib? Are there other methods to solve this?
Versions used:
AEM version - 6.5.20.0
Angular version - 13.4.0

When you build you can set  base-href ng build --output-path docs --base-href /your_project_name/
